# How can I set the geometric resolution of a primitive?

Tags: vertices, polycount, resolution

I'm having trouble creating a high resolution sphere in Blender.

I can create a sphere with Add -> Mesh -> UV Sphere.  This sphere will be viewed very close to the camera, and it's obvious (in Unity) that the object is not round.

There doesn't seem to be any way to set or increase the number of vertices / segments in the sphere either during creation or afterward.  Is there a menu I'm supposed to be seeing that's not in my view?

[image: blender view]

^ This is all I'm seeing in Blender.  No obvious way to set the sphere's resolution.

[image: unity view]

^ Sphere looks pointy in the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Blender 2.8

In Blender 2.8, after adding a UV sphere, a flyout appears on the bottom of the 3D viewport:

[image: Add UV Sphere Flyout]

I have no idea on how to access that with a keyboard shortcut.

#### earlier versions

If you press <kbd>T</kbd> before adding the UV sphere, you should see the "Transform" panel which allows you to set the  segments and rings.

[image: Object transform panel]

If you already have the UV sphere and want to modify it instead of creating a new one from scratch, you could use the Subdivision Surface ("Subsurf") modifier.

[image: Subsurf Modifier]

Comment: Perfect.  The simplest things are always the hardest to find info about (like blender keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

Right after the mesh is added, press <kbd>F6</kbd> to get a pop-up dialogue box to edit the [mesh primitive](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/primitives.html#common-options)[image]

Comment: F6 doesn't seem to do anything in my blender.

Comment: Only work when you just added the mesh, you can also try pressing LMB on it

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Does Blender's UI change completely every few months?

Comment: @WouterLievens: hopefully not. 2.8 was a major redesign regarding usability.

Comment: In Blender 2.81, it’s F9, not F6. But it only works when the panel is available in the bottom left corner anyway, so it seems largely pointless.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware 2.8 was such a big evolution.